# Regex expression for replacing string between two characters (including the characters)

Tags: javascript, regex

var x = "abc.cde:abc";

I want to replace everything between and including . and : with a space character.

resulting in abc abc

I can't seem to figure out Regex inclusive matches. Help would be greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var x = "abc.cde:abc";

x = x.replace(/\.[^:]*\:/g, ' '); // => "abc abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "abc.cde:abc";
x = x.replace(/\..*:/g, ' '))
```